# How to json string convert to php array?

Tags: php

I am trying to get php array from json string

```
$testData = "{
        'data' :[{
            'id' : '201120121',
            'bsid' : '200',
            'bspaymentcode' : '12',
            'service' : 'bed set',
            'cost' : '2000',
            'date_begin' : '12.12.14',
            'date_end' : '01.01.15' 
        } , 
        {
            'id' : '20133231',
            'bsid' : '220',
            'bspaymentcode' : '22',
            'service' : 'sport center',
            'cost' : '2000',
            'date_begin' : '12.12.14',
            'date_end' : '01.01.15' 
        }]
    }";

var_dump(json_decode($testData,true));exit;
```

But i have NULL. Any ideas?

Comment: Your json is invalid. It should use double quotes not single quotes for values.

Answer (score 6):

JSON uses double quotes for strings. Your string uses single quotes, therefore it's not valid JSON, and `json_decode` returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the variable's single quotes (your data content is from another variable), I think you can use `str_replace`, this is code for you

```
$testData = "{
        'data' :[{
            'id' : '201120121',
            'bsid' : '200',
            'bspaymentcode' : '12',
            'service' : 'bed set',
            'cost' : '2000',
            'date_begin' : '12.12.14',
            'date_end' : '01.01.15' 
        } , 
        {
            'id' : '20133231',
            'bsid' : '220',
            'bspaymentcode' : '22',
            'service' : 'sport center',
            'cost' : '2000',
            'date_begin' : '12.12.14',
            'date_end' : '01.01.15' 
        }]
    }";
$testData = str_replace("'", '"', $testData);

var_dump(json_decode($testData,true));exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap double quote(") with single quote(') will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yea it looks like everything is correct except your JSON syntax (you need double quotes not single quotes). Here is a great site to check your JSON string/object and it tells you what the issue is:

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/